# Get a specific value of a string_split in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, split

I have a string like this

0011.06.123.7-0

`SELECT STRING_SPLIT(NUMBER,'.')`

returns

| Values |
| --- |
| 0011 |
| 06 |
| 123 |

And now I only and always need the third value, in this case '123'
How do I select this proberly?

I already tried to get the third value with the Rownumber, but that didn't worked out.

Comment: For `STRING_SPLIT`, you must be using SQL Server 2022+.

Comment: Have you considered parsename()  ?

Comment: I have found a function named "SPLIT_PART" for postgreSQL, is there an equivalent in mssql?

Comment: Working example of parsename()   Select parsename('0011.06.123.7-0',2)   Provided you don't have more than 4 segments

Comment: Note that the solution with `PARSENAME` *assumes* that there will *always* be 3 delimited values; if you have a variable amount it may not be appropriate, and simply won't work if you have 5+.